# git-flow: why does "git-flow feature finish -S" still create a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-flow

I have locally developed a feature which consists of a couple of *"work in progress"* commits. When I'm going to finish this feature using `git-flow feature finish -S`, I would expect to get one clean commit in `develop`. However, I get an additional merge commit on top of the squashed commit which references my *"work in progress"* commits from the obsolete feature branch. What's the purpose of this behavior? Can this additional merge commit be skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea I have is, that the squashed commit is used to show all changes in one single commit, but keeping the history for whatever reason.

The usual way of using the squash commit to get rid of the detail commits, seems not to be supported by this command (don't know why).

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping to obtain, but looks like there is not better :/ Thanks.